# Build a WCF according to a reference service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am building a WCF service based on a given wsdl reference service given by Readify as a part of its technical interview process. What I did is that I built a client application that explores the methods exposed through this WCF, and then I started implementing my own version from this WCF.

I have finished the coding and the hosting part for my WCF version, and I had built another client that tests the results return from both WCFs, and everything seems okay. However, when I pass my WCF URL to the Readify testing app, it gives me this message:

I couldn't connect to that service with the contract I expected. The exception message was: There was no endpoint listening at {My WCF URL} that could accept the message.

Although, I am sure that the methods names and parameter types and the returned are the same.

Any hint???

Comment: Initial thoughts would be to look into svcutil.exe to build the interfaces and types exposed by the Readify service, then create the WCF service using those interfaces/types. I would also consider having your WCF service exposing the same WSDL as from the Readify service (where you have changed the endpoint elements to point to your host). This way you should be certain the your WCF service is following the same contract as what the testing app expects.

Comment: actually this is wt i have just started trying, running the svcutil tool, some folks call this method "WSDL first WCF" .. I will try also ur recommendation to make my WCF expose the same WSDL .. 
Really thankful for ur input .. wish me luck :)